# How to use method getRestultSetType()?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I want to know whether the resultset that I will be using is scrollable or not'
and I came to know that I can use `getResultSetType` method on the statement to find out.

I am using in the following manner:

```
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from studentinfo");
    int rs_type=stmt.getResultSetType();
    System.out.println(rs_type);
```

Is the above way of implementation is correct or not and if it is correct then it is returning **rs_type as 1003** what does that mean?

Comment: A hint that will make your life a lot easier: Java comes with [extensive documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/). Read (or search) it before asking questions that are already covered by the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

That refers to `java.sql.ResultSet#TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` constant, which means that your ResultSet object cursor may move only forward.

From the [ResultSet.getType()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getType--) javadoc:

> Retrieves the type of this `ResultSe`t object. The type is determined by the `Statement` object that created the result set.
>
> **Returns**:
>      `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`, `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`, or `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`

Answer (score 1):

From the JavaSE API documentation:

```
int getResultSetType()
                     throws SQLException
```

> Retrieves the result set type for ResultSet objects generated by this
>   Statement object.
>
> Returns: one of `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`,
>   `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`, or
>   `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`
>
> Throws: `SQLException` - if a database access error occurs or this
>   method is called on a closed Statement

So you should compare the returned value with those constants